Why Dyntopo with the Refine Method option on Subdivide Edges still Collapse edges in dense topology?
In Sculpt Mode, when using the Simplify tool with Dyntopo enabled, you have the choice between 3 Refine Methods :

Subdivide Edges
Collapse Edges
Subdivide Collapse

When I test it, Collapse Edges and Subdivide Collapse work as expected.
But when I select Subdivide Edges, the Simplify tool acts exactly like if Subdivide Collapse was still selected.
So rather than only subdivide edges in areas with less dense topology than the defined resolution, it also collapse edges in areas with denser topology than the defined resolution.
So is this a bug or is there something to do to make the tool work as expected?

As specified in the manual:
The Simplify brush is specifically meant for use with Dyntopo to remove/add detail in the mesh. Even when the Refine Method is set to Subdivide Edges, this brush is always able to collapse edges. This ensures that while focusing on adding detail to your sculpt, the Simplify brush can always be used to simplify and polish surfaces.
